# Android - displaying fractions using unicode

Tags: android

I am trying to make a fraction:

I am using this is a text view but it is not rendering very nicely:

```
"5"+'\u2044'+"9";
```

It does not turn the text into a nice fraction instead it sort of covers part of the numbers and squishes them together.

Any solutions or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup>5</sup>/<sub>9</sub>"));
```

Don't know if that will look good, but it's worth a shot. Otherwise, other than the single-glyph fractions like 1/2, I suspect you either will need to go without or render it yourself.

Comment: "Html.fromHtml" this is a little treasure.  Do you know where they list the HTML tags that are available?

Comment: They don't. I happened to blog on this very topic just yesterday: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: is it possible to make the fraction sign to be horizontally , so that the numbers would be one above the other?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Not in a `TextView`, except for those Unicode glyphs for standard fractions.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: One possibility is to use `<img>` tags and represent those fractions as bitmaps. That may get messy with differing font sizes, though.

Comment: @9patchcoder: Since I am not quite certain what you mean by that, I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide more details, code snippets, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: what I meant was 
after a string is cooked using this method and you gettext your textview, can you tell if it was generated using this html sup/sub method (i.e. it's a fraction) or it's just a "/" (division) character ?

Comment: @9patchcoder: Well, the actual return value from `getText()` will be a `Spanned`, and there will be `SuperscriptSpan` and `SubscriptSpan` objects marking the numerator and denominator of your fraction. However, there could be other superscripts or subscripts, depending on where the text came from. (I had examples, but I forgot that these comment boxes don't honor arbitrary HTML tags...)