# How to display fractions in android textview?

Tags: android, textview

I want to display `3½` on android text view. I tried doing it with unicode but no luck. Please see my code below. Can anyone please help.

```
additionalInfoString = additionalInfoString.replace("½",<sup><small>&frac12;</small></sup>);
```

Comment: look at this hope it's help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920726/android-displaying-fractions-using-unicode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use HTML format to show fractions

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("3<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>"));
```

Verify your HTML Text [here](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

[image]

As `Html.fromHtml(String s)` method has been depreciated. Take a look at this answer [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/4601149)

Comment: thank u Slientkiller...it worked...But my problem is not it is getting truncated on textview.Can you suggeset me anything for that

Comment: @androidDeveloer you need to set fixed height for this.

Comment: Elegant solution! You could also use `&frasl;` instead of plain `/` for the fraction line: `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("3<sup>1</sup>&frasl;<sub>2</sub>"));`

Comment: @msal you should have edit. I always appreciate better answer from anyone. :) edit it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html formatting of Android TextView. However you must add a extra space on the top and bottom to keep the fraction from being cut off.

```
  SpannableStringBuilder text = new SpannableStringBuilder();
  text.append("3");
  text.append("\n");
  text.append(Html.fromHtml("<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>"));
  text.append("\n");
```

P.S. : The above code is not tested (just a hunch)

Answer (score 1):

you can use unicode character directly as

```
tv.setText("3\u00BD");
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mTxtVw.setText(Html.fromHtml("3<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>"));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to create two `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` and manage it. because in  `Html.fromHtml` superscript text not comes with proper alignment . use some thing like below

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintext_sup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="1/2"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/maintext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```