# Html.fromHtml deprecated in Android N

Tags: android, deprecated, android-7.0-nougat

I am using `Html.fromHtml` to view html in a `TextView`.

```
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(mNews.getTitle());
...
...
mNewsTitle.setText(result);
```

But `Html.fromHtml` is now deprecated in Android N+

What/How do I find the new way of doing this?

Answer (score 815, accepted):

**update**:
as [@Andy mentioned below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n/37905107#52130841)  Google has created `HtmlCompat` which can be used instead of the method below. Add this dependency `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.1`
 to the build.gradle file of your app. Make sure you use the latest version of `androidx.core:core`.

This allows you to use:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

You can read more about the different flags on the [HtmlCompat-documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat.html)

**original answer:**
In Android N they introduced a new `Html.fromHtml` method. `Html.fromHtml` now requires an additional parameter, named flags. This flag gives you more control about how your HTML gets displayed.

On Android N and above you should use this new method. The older method is deprecated and may be removed in the future Android versions.

You can create your own Util-method which will use the old method on older versions and the newer method on Android N and above. If you don't add a version check your app will break on lower Android versions. You can use this method in your Util class.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
    if(html == null){
        // return an empty spannable if the html is null
        return new SpannableString("");
    }else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        // FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY is the behaviour that was used for versions below android N
        // we are using this flag to give a consistent behaviour
        return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

You can convert the `HTML.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY` into an additional parameter if you want. This gives you more control about it which flag to use.

You can read more about the different flags on the 
[Html class documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)

Comment: Which flag does the zero represent?

Comment: `Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY`

Comment: ah, waiting for something like HtmlCompat to appear

Comment: It's also useful to add a `//noinspection deprecation` comment just under the `else` to avoid lint warnings.

Comment: You can see what each of these flags do in this blog post: https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/html-tags-in-android-nougat-textview-9f3554d7b705

Comment: And this seems to be deprecated as well and can be replaced by

`Html.FromHtml(htmlText, Android.Text.FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);`

Comment: Why is it deprecated? What's better to use now? Why the need for the function you wrote, if the code behind the deprecated functions already use this flag?

Comment: For me @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") did not work. I used @Suppress("deprecation") instead.

Comment: @vanomart Aaaand `HtmlCompat` including `HtmlCompat.fromHtml` is a thing now =)

Comment: Core library has String extension `parseAsHtml()`  that will do exactly this

Answer (score 103):

I had a lot of these warnings and I always use FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY so I made a helper class called HtmlCompat containing the following:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            return Html.fromHtml(source);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same effect like the accepted answer, but +1 because of SuppressWarnings annotation

Comment: Can you give small explanation about this mode?

Comment: could you provide all HtmlCompact may be on git hub it looks cool

Comment: @shareef I would but it's really just a boring utility class with this single method in it....

Comment: You can also just use HtmlCompat and avoid checking Android version.

Answer (score 78):

Compare of the flags of fromHtml().

```
<p style="color: blue;">This is a paragraph with a style</p>

<h4>Heading H4</h4>

<ul>
   <li style="color: yellow;">
      <font color=\'#FF8000\'>li orange element</font>
   </li>
   <li>li #2 element</li>
</ul>

<blockquote>This is a blockquote</blockquote>

Text after blockquote
Text before div

<div>This is a div</div>

Text after div
```

[image: FROM_HTML FLAGS]

Comment: Can you please share input HTML also? This would help in better understanding the conversion.

Comment: I see that the style attributes are not implemented, is there a way to implement them?

Answer (score 66):

Or you can use `androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat`:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<b>HTML</b>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

[HtmlCompat docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat)

Comment: you can use this even on Android 5?

Comment: @CDrosos yes, it is part of support library

Answer (score 30):

If you are lucky enough to develop on Kotlin, 
just create an extension function:

```
fun String.toSpanned(): Spanned {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(this, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        return Html.fromHtml(this)
    }
}
```

And then it's so sweet to use it everywhere:

```
yourTextView.text = anyString.toSpanned()
```

Comment: you may save typings by remove `Spanned` and `return`

Answer (score 16):

**[fromHtml](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler))**

> This method was <s>**deprecated**</s> in ***API level 24***.

You should use **[FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)**

> Separate block-level elements with blank lines (two newline
>   characters) in between. This is the legacy behavior prior to N.

**Code**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
        {
            etOBJ.setText(Html.fromHtml("Intellij \n Amiyo",Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));

         }
 else
        {
           etOBJ.setText(Html.fromHtml("Intellij \n Amiyo"));
        }
```

**For Kotlin**

```
fun setTextHTML(html: String): Spanned
    {
        val result: Spanned = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
        } else {
            Html.fromHtml(html)
        }
        return result
    }
```

Call

```
 txt_OBJ.text  = setTextHTML("IIT Amiyo")
```

Comment: Can you give small explanation about this mode?

Comment: if you want SDK to handle version checks, use:                                                         `HtmlCompat.fromHtml("textWithHtmlTags", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)`

Answer (score 11):

If you're using **Kotlin**, I achieved this by using a Kotlin extension:

```
fun TextView.htmlText(text: String){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
    } else {
        setText(Html.fromHtml(text))
    }
}
```

Then call it like:

```
textView.htmlText(yourHtmlText)
```

Comment: you don't need to add the else part, fromHtml method handles it by default for lower api devices

Comment: You can replace the if/else with: `HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)`

Answer (score 9):

From official doc :

> `fromHtml(String)` method was deprecated in API level 24. use `fromHtml(String, int)`
>   instead.
>
> 1. `TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE` Option for `toHtml(Spanned, int)`: Wrap consecutive lines of text delimited by `'\n'` inside `<p>`
>      elements.
> 2. `TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL` Option for `toHtml(Spanned, int)`: Wrap each line of text delimited by `'\n'` inside a `<p>` or a `<li>`
>      element.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 6):

For Kotlin users, we can use `String.parseAsHtml()` extension function which uses [HtmlCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/text/HtmlCompat) which in turn has compatibility checks.

This is available from the android core kotlin extensions available from `androidx.core:core-ktx`

Answer (score 5):

Just to extend the answer from @Rockney and @k2col the improved code can look like:

```
@NonNull
public static Spanned fromHtml(@NonNull String html) {
    if (CompatUtils.isApiNonLowerThan(VERSION_CODES.N)) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

Where the `CompatUtils.isApiNonLowerThan`:

```
public static boolean isApiNonLowerThan(int versionCode) {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= versionCode;
}
```

The difference is that there are no extra local variable and the deprecation is only in `else` branch. So this will not suppress all method but single branch.

It can help when the Google will decide in some future versions of Android to deprecate even the `fromHtml(String source, int flags)` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
//noinspection deprecation
return Html.fromHtml(source);
```

to suppress inspection just for single statement but not the whole method.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        holder.notificationTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(notificationSucces.getMessage(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        holder.notificationTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(notificationSucces.getMessage()));

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

just make a function :

```
public Spanned fromHtml(String str){
  return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24 ? Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) : Html.fromHtml(str);
}
```

Comment: why not `FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT`?

Answer (score 2):

The framework class has been modified to require a flag to inform `fromHtml()` how to process line breaks. This was added in Nougat, and only touches on the challenge of incompatibilities of this class across versions of Android.

I've published a compatibility library to standardize and backport the class and include more callbacks for elements and styling:

> https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat

While it is similar to the framework's Html class, some signature changes were required to allow more callbacks. Here's the sample from the GitHub page:

```
Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, source, 0);
// You may want to provide an ImageGetter, TagHandler and SpanCallback:
//Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, source, 0,
//        imageGetter, tagHandler, spanCallback);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(fromHtml);
```

Comment: When I use your library on an app which uses `minSdkVersion 15` and `targetSdkVersion 23` I get a build error for _values-v24.xml_: `Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.` Your library targets API level 25, obviously. How can still I use it?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following to support basic html tags including ul ol li tags.
Create a Tag handler as shown below

```
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Html.TagHandler;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyTagHandler implements TagHandler {
    boolean first= true;
    String parent=null;
    int index=1;
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output,
                          XMLReader xmlReader) {

        if(tag.equals("ul")) parent="ul";
        else if(tag.equals("ol")) parent="ol";
        if(tag.equals("li")){
            if(parent.equals("ul")){
                if(first){
                    output.append("\n\t•");
                    first= false;
                }else{
                    first = true;
                }
            }
            else{
                if(first){
                    output.append("\n\t"+index+". ");
                    first= false;
                    index++;
                }else{
                    first = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set the text on Activity as shown below

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void init(){
        try {
            TextView help = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.help);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                help.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help_html),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, new MyTagHandler()));
            } else {
                help.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.help_html), null, new MyTagHandler()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And html text on resource string files as

<![CDATA[ ...raw html data ...]] >