# How to display html content (string) in a view(preferably textview and not webview)?

Tags: android, html, textview

I'm trying to show display an HTML string that I get as content from the server.

1)

```html
<img alt="Https%3a%2f%2fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2fuploads%2fcard%2fimage%2f131488%2fap_16181711733011" src="http://i.amz.mshcdn.com/yTdMVoJcGanbLCen51NCXh2HHgc=/575x323/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F131488%2FAP_16181711733011.jpg">
<div>
  <a href="http://twitter.com/share?via=Mashable&text=The+Academy+just+took+a+huge+step+toward+ending+%23OscarsSoWhite&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2016%2F06%2F29%2Facademy-incoming-class-oscars-so-white%2F%3Futm_campaign%3DMash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial%26utm_cid%3DMash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">
    <img alt="Feed-tw" src="http://a.amz.mshcdn.com/assets/feed-tw-f7c0a094d16b7ee7c91a1e50839a8e00.jpg" border="0">
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmashable.com%2F2016%2F06%2F29%2Facademy-incoming-class-oscars-so-white%2F%3Futm_campaign%3DMash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial%26utm_cid%3DMash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&src=sp">
    <img alt="Feed-fb" src="http://a.amz.mshcdn.com/assets/feed-fb-c0a21e8841794479b8086c32c6f24ba1.jpg" border="0">
  </a>
</div>
<div>
  <p>LOS ANGELES — For all the grief the Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences has taken for <span>#OscarsSoWhite — much of it deserved, some incidental to the industry it represents — you can't say they haven't made an effort to make this right. Not after Wednesday, anyway.</span>
  </p>
  <p><span>AMPAS just announced <a href="http://www.app.oscars.org/class2016/?hq_e=el&hq_m=467892&hq_l=1&hq_v=92c4c068ef">its incoming class for 2016</a>: 683 active actors, directors, writers and other Hollywood operators. And get this: 41% of those are people of color.</span>
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>SEE ALSO: <a data-crackerjax="#post-slider" href="http://mashable.com/2016/06/19/hollywood-asian-americans/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Hollywood is finally opening up to Asian Americans</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <p><span>That new infusion moves the needle from 8% people of color in the Academy overall (an abysmal number) to 11% (a somewhat less abysmal number). But that's how you turn an aircraft carrier — one hard-fought degree at a time.</span>  <a href="http://mashable.com/2016/06/29/academy-incoming-class-oscars-so-white/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Read more...</a>
  </p>
</div>More about <a href="http://mashable.com/category/oscars/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Oscars</a>, <a href="http://mashable.com/category/awards/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Awards</a>,
<a
href="http://mashable.com/category/oscarssowhite/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Oscarssowhite</a>, <a href="http://mashable.com/category/the-academy-awards/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">The Academy Awards</a>, and <a href="http://mashable.com/category/movies/?utm_campaign=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial&utm_cid=Mash-Prod-RSS-Feedburner-All-Partial">Movies</a>
  <img
  height="1" alt="" width="1" src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/Mashable/~4/CCdsReJZ4AI">
```

2)

```html
<table cellpadding="2" border="0" cellspacing="7">
  <tr>
    <td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNHMsFZzwgIWn_QVXz1i4ja_vzCAWg&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=https://www.nhl.com/news/oilers-trade-taylor-hall-to-devils-for-adam-larsson/c-281082608"><img height="80" alt="" width="80" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjZ0_-OrtEy4EYRH9yuujd-xVA-SSV2vPMNVrk1Vu38s074mpStUsGmKpMlodG1uEN8Fdy0_g" border="1"><br><font size="-2">NHL.com</font>
      </a>
      </font>
    </td>
    <td valign="top"><font><br><div><img height="1" alt="" width="1"></div><div><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNHMsFZzwgIWn_QVXz1i4ja_vzCAWg&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=https://www.nhl.com/news/oilers-trade-taylor-hall-to-devils-for-adam-larsson/c-281082608"><b>Oilers trade Hall to Devils for Larsson</b></a><br><font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">NHL.com</font>
      </b>
      </font>
      <br><font size="-1">The Edmonton Oilers traded left wing Taylor Hall to the New Jersey Devils for defenseman Adam Larsson on Wednesday. Hall, 24, had 65 points (26 goals, 39 assists) in 82 games this season. Taken by the Oilers with the first pick of the 2010 NHL Draft <b>...</b></font>
      <br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNHU8SI0YuY45TFYS5bM4lPDrgwjIA&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=http://www.sbnation.com/nhl/2016/6/29/12061076/edmonton-oilers-trade-taylor-hall-to-devils-for-defenseman-adam-larsson">Edmonton Oilers trade Taylor Hall to Devils for defenseman Adam Larsson</a><font color="#6f6f6f" size="-1"><span>SB Nation</span></font></font>
      <br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNGKLDn9L7d4te1L2k3xcRGvzmTizQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=http://www.foxsports.com/nhl/story/devils-acquire-former-no-1-pick-tyler-hall-from-oilers-062916">Devils acquire former No. 1 pick Tyler Hall from Oilers (Jun 29, 2016)</a><font color="#6f6f6f" size="-1"><span>FOXSports.com</span></font></font>
      <br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNG5pZAY6YTksB1rBuBI3pDbnv2Kvg&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=http://nesn.com/2016/06/nhl-trade-rumors-oilers-deal-taylor-hall-to-devils-for-adam-larsson/">NHL Trade Rumors: Oilers Deal Taylor Hall To Devils For Adam Larsson</a><font color="#6f6f6f" size="-1"><span>NESN.com</span></font></font>
      <br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNFEFnTT_HOQsw3Blv_2p_-V1jnEZg&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=http://www.sportingnews.com/nhl/news/taylor-hall-trade-nj-devils-oilers-adam-larsson-nhl-free-agency-rumors/26cy0kuycevx1t2vnd50opg97"><span>Sporting News</span></a> -<a href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNGApMEvfFT-RJ8XNmEkd_yvzSXIXg&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52779144035033&ei=-it0V6DLG9OEhQGy5JOwDA&url=http://www.cbssports.com/nhl/news/oilers-send-taylor-hall-to-devils-in-stunning-trade/"><span>CBS sports.com (blog)</span></a></font>
      <br><font size="-1"><a href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=dphuwoc95lSJMYMiW383gX0akIahM&authuser=0&ned=us&topic=h"><span><b>all 28 news articles »</b></span></a></font>
      </div>
      </font>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The method `Html.fromHtml()` has been deprecated, also it does not handle `iframe` tags.

Comment: Why don't you use `Html.fromHtml(texts,0) then` ?

Answer (score 0):

try below answer.. hope this solves your problem. Let me know if you still face any issues

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/2779404

Comment: I tried that, but it does not handle the embedded video tags.

Comment: You can try another way round to handle your requirement.                      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<iframe src");
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlString);
while (m.find())
    htmlString= m.replaceAll("<a href");

p = Pattern.compile("frameborder=.*</iframe>");
m = p.matcher(htmlString);
while (m.find())
    htmlString= m.replaceAll(">CLICK TO WATCH</a>");`

Comment: That is a nice workaround, but is there no way to sort of embed them in the textview in between the text lines?

Comment: I think, it is not possible to handle <iframe> tag. I have come across a site where they have listed all possible tags supported by HTML.fromHtml API. Please check this for your reference [link](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) .     You can only acheive this with WebView.

Comment: Is it possible to insert a dynamic videoview in between the spanned text in a textview?. I have seen many apps( not the code ) that don't use a WebView but have a embedded video for example - Palabre. So there must be a way?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
Html.fromHtml(String, int) //for 24 api and more
```

and

```
Html.fromHtml(String, int) //for old apis
```

Comment: These two lines are basically the same.

Comment: As i have mentioned, Html.fromHtml() does not handle the <iframe> (embedded video tags). It just removes them from the spanned string.