# Android TextView Hyperlink

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I'm implementing a TextView with a string containing two hyperlinks as below but the links are not opening a new browser window:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="@string/agree_terms_privacy"/>
```

In string.xml

```
<string name="agree_terms_privacy">By continuing, you agree to our <a href="http://link1/terms">Terms of Use</a> and read the <a href="http://link1/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></string>
```

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734270/how-do-i-make-links-in-a-textview-clickable ?

Comment: Check answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2746708/2435238

Comment: I suggest to get familiar with Spannable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696986/how-to-set-the-part-of-the-text-view-is-clickable.

Comment: If it's helpful to you would you mind marking my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 40):

Here is the solution that worked for me, after looking through multiple Stack Overflow posts. I've tailored it to your implementation:

**1.** **Remove autolink in favor of using LinkMovementMethod, and set linksClickable to true**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/termsOfUse"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/agree_terms_privacy"/>
```

If you use the `android:autoLink="web"` property then you'll have to override it with `textView.setAutoLinkMask(0);` before calling `setText()` on your TextView. You can also set the link to be clickable in your activity instead like in Harshal's answer if you prefer, but I left it since you already had it in the layout. I also added an id to your TextView called `termsOfUse` which we'll use later.

**2.** **Replace < with `&lt;` in strings.xml and remove double quotes around the url**

This is because when you retrieve the string resource, it won't parse the embedded html correctly, and for some reason it doesn't escape the double quotes. So instead of:

```
<string name="agree_terms_privacy">By continuing, you agree to our <a href="http://link1/terms">Terms of Use</a> and read the <a href="http://link1/privacy">Privacy Policy</a></string>
```

you'll want to do:

```
<string name="agree_terms_privacy">By continuing, you agree to our &lt;a href=http://link1/terms>Terms of Use&lt;/a> and read the &lt;a href=http://link1/privacy>Privacy Policy&lt;/a></string>
```

**3. Parsing the string resource and binding it to our TextView**

```
Spanned policy = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.agree_terms_privacy));
TextView termsOfUse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.termsOfUse);
termsOfUse.setText(policy);
termsOfUse.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

*Note:* Html.fromHtml has been deprecated in API 24 (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n) for more information on how to handle this if needed). We use this method to get the expected HTML formatting from our string.

Comment: Thanks, i tried multiple solutions for the same use-case(two links in a single textview) and this one indeed works!

Comment: This solution works for a few links. Important note - links should start from http:// or https://

Comment: after searching for half-hour finally got the solution. Thanks +1

Comment: this save my day

Comment: I was missing this bit: textView.setAutoLinkMask(0);
This post saved the day, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Have a look on below code snippet, hope it helps,

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: How to make that link open in webview?

Answer (score 8):

This works for me

Add this in your textview:

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:clickable="true"
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJxyfyDyHU

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to have two `TextViews` since ou want two different actions:

```
TextView yourTermsOfUseTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
yourTermsOfUseTextView.setOnclickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(your_download_link));
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
```

Repeat to the privacy policy.

Comment: How to fetch only the link from textview in OnClick method?

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code in your **Textview**

```
android:autoLink="email"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like bellow..

1. textview xml

   ```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_welcome_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
   ```
2. In activity

   ```
    TextView   tv_welcome_message=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_welcome_message); 
    tv_welcome_message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = " <a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
    tv_welcome_message.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.java

```
 TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    t2.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I removed most of the attributes on my TextView to match what was in the demo

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txtCredits"/>
```

Don't forget to remove autoLink="web" if you are calling setMovementMethod()

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Linkify](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/util/Linkify)

```kotlin
textView.text = text
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
Add this in your textview

```
android:linksClickable="true"
android:autoLink="all"
```

AutoLink Values: all, email, map, none, phone, web  Controls whether links such as urls and email addresses are automatically found and converted to clickable links. The default value is "none", disabling this feature.