# Remove part of String Android

Tags: android, string

in my app I get a String from RSS fedd item(tag description)and put it in a ListView but the String looks like this:

[image]

I try to remove the tag with this method but doesn't work:

```
private String refactor(String mess) {
        int indexToRemove = mess.lastIndexOf("<strong>");
        String toBeReplaced = mess;
        if(indexToRemove >= 0 ){
             toBeReplaced = mess.substring(0, indexToRemove);
        }
        int newIndex = toBeReplaced.lastIndexOf("</strong>");
        String messFinal = toBeReplaced;
        if(newIndex >= 0){
            messFinal = toBeReplaced.substring(0, newIndex);
        }
        return messFinal;
    }
```

Comment: You mean the "<strong>" tag?

Comment: the "<strong>" tag yes

Answer (score 3):

Would be better to not to remove `HTML` tags, but render them correctly.

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));`

Comment: like this description = Html.toHtml(Html.fromHtml(data.getString("description")));?

Comment: `descriptionTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(data.getString("description"));`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use replace() from String?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want render the HTML correctly you could just use

```
Spanned parsedHtmlString = Html.fromHtml(htmlString)
```

instaed if rendering the html can cause you some layout problems you can use this to remove the html tags

```
Spanned strippedHtmlString = Html.fromHtml(htmlString).toString()
```

Remember that those metdods are deprecated starting from Android N, so you need to use something like this for compiling with API 24+

```
Spanned result;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    result = Html.fromHtml(htmlString, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY); //add .toString() to remove html tags
} else {
    result = Html.fromHtml(htmlString); //add .toString() to remove html tags
}
```

took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/2910520)

**EDIT**
Based on your comment, i think you should go with this:

```
public RssItem(Parcel source) { 
    Bundle data = source.readBundle();
    title = Html.fromHtml(data.getString("title")).toString(); 
    link = Html.fromHtml(data.getString("link")).toString(); 
    pubDate = (Date) data.getSerializable("pubDate"); 
    description = Html.fromHtml(data.getString("description")).toString(); 
    content = Html.fromHtml(data.getString("content")).toString(); 
    feed = data.getParcelable("feed"); 
}
```

i've omitted some objects because it really depends on what they contain.
Moreover you should do some check for null before parsing them with Html.fromHtml

Comment: I get item from rss fedd

Comment: I get rss fedd item with this method
public RssItem(Parcel source) {

        Bundle data = source.readBundle();
        title = data.getString("title");
        link = data.getString("link");
        pubDate = (Date) data.getSerializable("pubDate");
        description = data.getString("description");
        content = data.getString("content");
        feed = data.getParcelable("feed");

    }
 
 And 'here that I have to use the method Html.fromHtml?

Comment: @Marduk i've updated my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for removing html tags.

```
private String refactor(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```