# Android studio project not working on Android 9.0 or higher but working fine on Android 7 or 8

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

here is the project code: https://github.com/harpreetahluwalia/SmartMediaPlayer

It's working fine in android 7 and android 8 
but not working in android 9 or higher

It's giving some warnings like these:

```
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that you are using a function which is deprecated on API 24 (Android 7.0).

In `VideoFolder.java` file line 39,

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>Smart Video Player </font>"));`

You are using `Html.fromHtml()` which is deprecated.

Use `HtmlCompat` instead. Please do refer this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37905107/1770409

Tip on finding deprecated warnings and other issues,

In Android Studio, go to `Analyze -> Inspect Code` then select the scope you want to inspect. It will show all the warnings you have to pay attention for.