# Display bold letters in listview fetched from sqlite DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have fetching data from sqlite database. What i want is to display with bold the "Name" of each of my products.

Here is the code:

```
    fullProductDetails = "<b>Name: </b>"+data.getString(1) + "| Price: " + data.getString(2) + "| Quantity: " + data.getString(3);
```

The problem is that it's displaying the "b" character instead of bold in my listview.

**Update**

Here is a bit more of code:

```
Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            //get the value from the database in column 1
            //then add it to the ArrayList
            totalPrice=Float.parseFloat(data.getString(2))*Float.parseFloat(data.getString(3));
            fullProductDetails = "<b>Name: </b>"+data.getString(1) + "| Price: " + data.getString(2) + "| Quantity: " + data.getString(3);
            listData.add(fullProductDetails+" <b>Total Price: </b>"+totalPrice);
        }

//create the list adapter and set the adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is the screenshot. You can see two times "B" because i was testing something else. Ignore the second.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot and a bit more of code?

Comment: @Renis1235 I have made the update. Let me know if it's more clear for you!

Comment: How do you add the elements to the list, can you include that one too?

Answer (score 1):

HTML formatted text won't work for native non-web `TextView` in Android. or any other not-web-based framework/system...

you should format this text with [`Spans`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans), this is recommended way with plenty of possibilities

BUT for your simple case (handling only bold `<b>` tag) you may use `Html.fromHtml` method

```
fullProductDetails = ...
Spanned fullProductDetailsSpanned = Html.fromHtml(fullProductDetails);
textView.setText(fullProductDetailsSpanned);
```

read carefully [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n) (use compat method posted in answer) and [THIS](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) (only few tags are supported by this method, rest would be stripped out, but bold is on the list)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have a textView to display these! I only have the listView!

Comment: `ListView` contains some list items and in your case these are `TextView`s, supplied by adapter you have set. if you have simple instance, e.g. `ArrayAdapter<String>` then you may migrate to `ArrayAdapter<Spannable>` (and `ArrayList<String> listData` also), but the best option would be to write own adapter or at least override `getView()` method

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Name: </b>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Name: </b>"));
}
```

or directly:

```java
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Name: </b>"));
```