# Storing Fractional character in string values android

Tags: android, xml

When storing fractional numbers eg 1/2 in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="array_fractionals">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>1/2</item>
     <item>1/5</item>
    <item>1/8</item>
</string-array>
```

It get a suggestion to use it like:

```
    <item><![CDATA[&#8531;]]></item>
    <item><![CDATA[&#188;]]></item>
```

And when I take suggestion retrive values:

```
String[] array_frac=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_fractionals);
            numberPickerTwo.setDisplayedValues(array_frac);
```

It won't print "1/2" but will show the below:
what is the mechanism required to decode that to fractional character?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong unicode/escape code values.
Update your unicode values to following:

```
<string-array name="array_fractionals">
    <item>0</item>
    <item><![CDATA[\u00BD]]></item>   // values for 1/2
    <item><![CDATA[\u2155]]></item>  // values for 1/5
</string-array>
```

[Unicode values](https://graphemica.com/%E2%85%95) - refer this link to find all required unicode values (look for c, java unicode values)

**Final Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great. thank you. I am wondering why Android studio suggested me wrong unicodes . but this one works. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
<string-array name="array_fractionals">
    <item>0</item>
    <item tools:ignore="TypographyFractions">1/2</item>
    <item>1/5</item>
    <item>1/8</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this:-

```
Spanned[] spanneds = new Spanned[]{
            Html.fromHtml("<sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>"),
            Html.fromHtml("<sup>1</sup>/<sub>5</sub>"),
            Html.fromHtml("<sup>1</sup>/<sub>8</sub>")
    };
```

and use this array in text

```
yourtextview.setText(spanneds[1]);
```

which give you this output :-

[image]

Comment: [Html.fromHtml  is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904739/html-fromhtml-deprecated-in-android-n) ,   consider switching to the latest one